# SASS invalid syntax hexadecimal color on 8 degit with rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, hex

I tried to use native the RGBA syntax (`#0abf3055`) with SASS (in rails 6 app project):

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0abf3055, #22242F 30%)
```

but I got :

> Invalid CSS after "": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "#0abf3055"

if i replace by `rgba(#0abf30, 0.33)`, or just `#0abf30` it works, so its 8 degit syntax who have a problem with SASS.

But in documentation it's ok : https://sass-lang.com/playground/#eJwzMNRLzUnNTc0t4VJQSEpMzk4vyi/NS9HNzE1MT7VSyMnMS00s0k0vSkzJTM0r0SjJVyjKTM8o0VFQNkhMSjM2MDUFMo2MjEyM3BSMDVQ1ubgAdAgY1w==

So, how can I use native 8 digits syntax for color with SASS on rails ?

Comment: What SASS library and version are you using?

Comment: Rails 6 by default ships with the `sassc` gem if remember correctly which uses the long dead LibSass C implementation of SASS. Older versions used the Ruby compiler which has been dead for even longer. The only SASS parser thats currently being updated is DartSass. There is a [dartsass-rails gem](https://github.com/rails/dartsass-rails) but it may not be compatibile with the Rails 6 assets pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How can I use native 8 digits syntax for color with SASS on rails?

You use [Dart Sass](https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass/) which is the only currently supported SASS implementation.

Rails historically went from the original [Ruby SASS compiler](https://sass-lang.com/ruby-sass/) to [LibSass](https://sass-lang.com/libsass/). Both of which are long dead and do not support all the modern features/functions of the language. The `sass-rails` and `sassc-rails` gems integrate these old deprechiated parsers with Rails.

If you're using the old sprockets asset pipeline for your stylesheets you may be able to use the [dartsass-sprockets gem](https://github.com/tablecheck/dartsass-sprockets) after installing the dependencies for Dart Sass.

But you may want to consider ignoring the issue until upgrading to Rails 7 and making a decision about where you want to go in terms of assets handling.